# Python Xlsxwriter Conditional Format 'containing' Criteria is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am trying to format some of the cells based on a condition. The thing is 'containing' criteria is not working at all. I took a look at the source code, but formula seems to be right.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('C2:C1500', {'type': 'text',
                                          'criteria': 'containing',
                                          'value': 'someString',
                                          'format': format1})
```

Thanks in the advance

Comment: Did you try other 'criteria''s values as well? like : `'begins with',`  `'criteria':'not containing',` or `'criteria': ''ends with',`

Comment: I tried 'equals' and it is working fine. Strange, there is no error messages as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('conditional_format.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#29bc66'})

worksheet.write('A1', 'baz')
worksheet.write('A2', 'foo')
worksheet.write('A3', 'bar')
worksheet.write('A4', 'food')

worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A4',
                             {'type': 'text',
                              'criteria': 'containing',
                              'value': 'foo',
                              'format':   format1
                              })

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was about the excel viewer. Weirdly, it was not displaying the cells that are colored by 'containing' criteria

Comment: And how did you solved it? I have the same issue